# Basic OpenGL program crashes, but works with gdb

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I copied the first program in the OpenGL Reference Guide for an incredibly basic GLUT OpenGL program.

I am using the Code::Blocks IDE and running on Ubuntu 12.10.

I am using an ATI Mobile Radeon 4670 with the fglrx driver.

I am using this code to make sure my environment was working properly.
Here is the code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.25,0.25,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75,0.25,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75,0.75,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.25,0.75,0.0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("hello");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I figured this was the simplest code I could run and hope would compile. After some fenangling with the `include/` and `lib/` directories (`/usr/include` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`), I managed to get it to compile with no errors.

When ran either from within Code::Blocks or using the terminal, I get a segmentation fault. A shadow of a window appears but then it is destroyed and the program exits.

The really strange part is when I try to debug it. Selecting "Debug" from within Code::Blocks or using gdb myself (running `gdb <program>` and then `run`) on the command line, it runs just fine. No errors or issues are encountered whatsoever and it executes as expected.

This makes it extremely difficult for me to figure out what the problem is. I had gdb check a generated core file from executing normally, but all it said was

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f9ee3a5815c in ?? ()
```

Real big help. Any ideas? I might have something wrong with my configuration, so ask away.

Comment: On Linux, OpenGL is always easier to debug if you use the open source drivers.  This has nothing to do with the politics of open source, or even access to the source code (however nice that is).  The open source drivers are simply more stable and usually Valgrind-clean.

Comment: Also, the program looks fine and works for me.  So that's another reason to try installing different drivers.  Does `glxgears` work on your system? (`apt-get install mesa-utils`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, since I never used glut, but [this](http://davidwparker.com/2011/07/22/opengl-screencast-hello-world-glut/) site seems to suggest calling glutInitDisplayMode like this

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);

While you call it like this

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

Comparing the two makes me wonder if you should maybe switch your two parameters?

edit:
Nevermind me, I'm being retarded. Those are not 2 parameters ofcourse >< they are simply OR'd. It's 9 AM here and I haven't slept, so forgive my stupidity :<

Comment: Regarding your comment on a deleted answer about "installing OpenGL", yes it is possible to install or uninstall OpenGL implementations.  It's just a user-space library, like LibPNG or GTK -- files you can add or delete from your system.  I have three implementations to choose from on my system -- a buggy one from ATI, a feature-incomplete one from Mesa, and a software implementation.  Yes, the OpenGL library is separate from the drivers.

Comment: Ofcourse you can remove the files, or even download the files and copy them to your compiler's lib folder. But IMO that is not the same as installing, since installing doesn't involve more then simply running am executable. And yes, I am aware of it, that an installer basically just decompresses and copies some files to some folder, In that regard you are totally right :).

Comment: "Installing" means preparing the program or library for use.  An "installer" is a kind of program that installs programs or libraries, but it is not the only way to install things.  You can install libraries or programs manually, by copying the files.  I'm guessing you are a Windows user, because most programs on Linux and OS X are installed without running an installer -- either by manually copying files, running a makefile target, or using a package manager.

Comment: Also, it is a mistake to call it the compiler's lib folder.  All OpenGL implementations I know must be installed in the **system** library directory where they can be found by the loader.  The compiler might not even be installed.  The compiler does have a separate library directory, where you can find bits of runtime code.  OpenGL will not be installed in this directory because OpenGL is not part of the runtime provided with the compiler.